# How does std::string construct an object with the name as its constructor argument?

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>          
#include <iostream>        

std::string(foo);          

int main()                 
{                          
    std::cout << foo.size() << "\n";                                                
    return 0;              
}
```

Results in `0`, instead of an expected compile error for `foo` being undefined.

How is it able to do this? What is this called?

Comment: Are you asking where foo is defined/declared?

Comment: If doesn't. That's equivalent to `std::string foo;` You declared an object foo of type `std:string`.

Answer (score 11):

```
std::string(foo);  //#1
```

is the same as

```
std::string (foo); //#2
```

is the same as

```
std::string foo; //#3
```

The parentheses in `#2` are redundant. They are needed in `#1` as there is no whitespace separating `std::string` and `foo`.

Comment: Great answer, much easier to understand than the linked duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thank you. But it is hard to convince the "hammer-holders" about this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The definition `std::string(foo);` calls the *default* constructor of `std::string`. The default constructor by definition is the one that can be called without arguments, and indeed you do not provide one.

A default-constructed string is `empty`, so its size is indeed 0.